# Rails 3.2.7 and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to, actioncontroller

First of all, pretty new to Rails. I've been following a tutorial on using the 'link_to' command - basically, I have some links with text 'About Us', 'FAQ', 'Contact Us', and I want them to link to their respective pages.

Following the tutorial, the code in my contact_us.html.erb file goes like this:

```
<%= link_to "About Us", {:controller => ‘static_pages’, :action => ’about_us’} %>
```

My controller is called `static_pages_controller.rb` and I have an `about_us` method in that file, with no code in it:

```
def about_us
end
```

My controller code is:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def about_us
  end

  def faq
  end

  def contact_us
  end

  def t_and_c
  end

  def t_and_c_competition
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

I get the error:

> NameError in Static_pages#contact_us
>
> undefined local variable or method `‘static_pages'......etc

Any ideas what's wrong? I think it might be because the tutorial is for ruby 1.8.6 and Rails  2.0.2, and I have Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.2.7. I heard Rails is notorious for not being backwards compatible. Should I change my code? To what? Thanks for any help.

C.

Comment: Hi, added it in above. Changed < ApplicationController to BaseController, but got the error 'uninitialized constant BaseController'

Comment: Do you have  route declared for the static pages?

Comment: **Your version of Rails is out-of-date and vulnerable to numerous security vulnerabilities! Upgrade immediately!**. Further, Ruby 1.8.7 will no longer be supported in June, you should switch to Ruby 1.9 or 2.0 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think your problem it's you are using `’` instead of normal single quotes (') or doubled quotes (") when passing the parameters values in the link_to method

Change this:

```
<%= link_to "About Us", {:controller => ‘static_pages’, :action => ’about_us’} %>
```

to this:

```
<%= link_to "About Us", {:controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'about_us'} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my routes.rb:

get "static_pages/about_us"

and now it works. Thanks for your help!